# Implementing Dijkstra's algorithm in Java

Tags: java, graph-theory, dijkstra

I've done a fair bit of reading around this, and know that discussions regarding this algorithm in Java have been semi-frequent. My issue with implementing Dijkstra's algorithm in Java is simply that I'm not sure how to prepare my data.

I have a set of coordinates within an array, and a set of 1s and 0s in a matrix that represent whether there is a path between the points that the coordinates represent. My question is, how do I present this information so that I can search for the best path with Dijkstra? I have seen many people create a "Node" class, but they never seem to store the coordinates within that Node. Is there some standardized way of creating this kind of structure (I suppose it's a graph?) that I am simply missing?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A node doesn't need coordinates for Dijkstra's. It just needs **n** number of edges, each with a weighting. If you want to add co-ordinates to a node, go for it.

Comment: You can use the coordinates to determine the distances between nodes (pythagorean theorem) and use those as edge weights for the algorithm, but if you expect serious help from the Stackoverflow community you should include your code. Check out this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Wikipedia:  [Graph (abstract data type): Representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)#Representations).  A quick Google search turns up several other articles on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main options:
 1. You can use an adjacency matrix in which rows an columns represent your nodes. The value matrix[x, y] must be the weight(e.g. distance/cost etc.) to travel from x to y. You could use the Euclidian distance to calculate these values from your coordinate array;
 2. You can implement a couple of classes (Node, Edge - or just Node with a internal Map to another node and the weight as a map value) - it is a graph indeed.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is what I was looking for!